# Extract the IDs in the table by unique drug group with different date of service

Tags: sql-server, databricks-sql

I have to identify the individuals with ≥2 unique drugs, each with ≥2 claims on different dates of services.

| ID | Drug | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | aaa | 01/01/2022 |
| 111 | aaa | 01/15/2022 |
| 111 | bbb | 03/02/2022 |
| 111 | bbb | 04/06/2022 |
| 111 | ccc | 02/02/2022 |
| 222 | fff | 06/11/2022 |
| 222 | fff | 06/20/2022 |
| 222 | ccc | 08/25/2022 |
| 222 | ddd | 04/06/2022 |

Desired output for the above table is ID: 111 (which has 2 different drugs, each with different dates) excluding the ccc drug i.e it should extract only the desired rows.

Kindly suggest any query to complete the above statement.

```
select id, drug, date, count(*) as claims_ct
  from Table
  group by id,drug,date 
  having count(distinct drug) >= 2
  and count(distinct date) >= 2;
```

The above query responds "Query returned no results" in databricks.

Comment: remove the drag and date from `select` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for your suggestion. It works well, but the output also retrieves 222 IDs.

Comment: I see, I think I've misunderstood your requirements

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can use having below by comparing the min date vs the max date, grouped by id and drug.

```
select id,drug
    from Table
    group by id, drug
    having  min(date) <> max(Date)
```

Returning detail rows along with the summary will require a query for the rank of dates in each id, drug partition and then a filter against that value.

```
select * from
(
    select id, drug, date, row_number() over(partition by id, drug order by date) as claims_ct
        from Table
)as X
where
    claims_ct >= 2
```